# Mocking HttpContext.Session in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm using xUnit with Moq to write unit tests for my app.
However, I'm having a hard time to mock the session.

The system under test is a controller action, the method under test uses a `TempData["UserMessage"]` which always is null as Session isn't initialized.

This is a printscreen of how I'm trying to mock the dependency.
[image]

**Error thrown is at line 65 and is following**
[image]

Comment: Controllers should be dumb, you should instead have a service and test those.

Comment: I do have services where I store my logic. You mean one shouldn't test it at all? My intent was to test if it returned correct usermessage upon error/correct values sent in.

Comment: You're just testing that the framework does its thing, I usually try to avoid that.

Comment: I'm trying to digest what you are writing, but I can't see why I shouldn't test that our actions does various service method calls in correct order etc. Do  you have any link to what you are suggesting? I'm really interested in how thin/stupid  they should be.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... answered it

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is to avoid having "fat controllers". My controllers literally have the model or arguments they need to execute against a corresponding service. Ideally, your controller actions are a single call with a lot of attributes that describe the endpoint, consider the following:

```
public class MyThinController : Controller
{
    [
        HttpGet,
        Route("api/[controller]/foos/{bar}"),
        Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policies.StackoverflowOp))
    ]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetFoo([FromRoute] Bar bar,
                                      [FromServices] IExampleService service)
        => service.GetAsync(bar);
}
```

Then, your only concern should be that given a `bar` the implementation of `IExampleService` does correctly get a `Foo`.

But if you're completely not willing to do it the correct way, there is always a way to do it the wrong way. You're actually looking for the `ActionContext.HttpContext` which is moq-ready.

Comment: Thanks David, this is makes a lot of sense :)